# Why am I getting the "Study Error (9000) orders reached" message?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I converted an existing indicator into a strategy, I'm trying to learn pinescript, and I keep getting the 9000 orders reached error regardless of timeframe. How can I fix this? When I run it as an indicator it doesn't throw any errors. I've tried this from the 1m to 1D and haven't had any luck.  Please help!

```
strategy("k1", overlay=true, precision=0, explicit_plot_zorder=true, max_labels_count=500)

timeFilter = year == 2023

// Get user input
sensitivity = input.float(2.8, "  Sensitivity (0.5 - 10)", 0.5, 10, step=0.1)
emaEnergy   = input.bool(true, "EMA Energy")
keltner_length = input(10, "Keltner Channel Length")
atrPeriod = input(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.5, "Factor", step = 0.01)
// Position Sizing 
Risk = input.float(2, "Position Size * 10,000", step=0.1, minval=0, maxval=100)/100 
long_qty = math.floor(strategy.equity * Risk) 
short_qty = math.floor(strategy.equity * Risk) 
// Keltner Channel function
keltner_channel(src, length) =>
    ma = ta.sma(src, length)
    rangec = high - low
    upper = ma + rangec
    lower = ma - rangec
    [upper, lower]
// Modified Supertrend function using Keltner Channel
supertrend(_src, factor, atrLen, kel_length) =>
    [upperKeltner, lowerKeltner] = keltner_channel(_src, kel_length)
    rangec = upperKeltner - lowerKeltner
    upperBand = _src + factor * rangec
    lowerBand = _src - factor * rangec
    prevLowerBand = nz(lowerBand[1])
    prevUpperBand = nz(upperBand[1])
    lowerBand := lowerBand > prevLowerBand or close[1] < prevLowerBand ? lowerBand : prevLowerBand
    upperBand := upperBand < prevUpperBand or close[1] > prevUpperBand ? upperBand : prevUpperBand
    int direction = na
    float superTrend = na
    prevSuperTrend = superTrend[1]

    if na(rangec[1])
        direction := 1
    else if prevSuperTrend == prevUpperBand
        direction := close > upperBand ? -1 : 1
    else
        direction := close < lowerBand ? 1 : -1
    superTrend := direction == -1 ? lowerBand : upperBand
    [superTrend, direction]
// Get Components
ema1        = ta.ema(high,  9)
ema2        = ta.ema(high, 12)
ema3        = ta.ema(high, 15)
ema4        = ta.ema(high, 18)
ema5        = ta.ema(high, 21)
ema6        = ta.ema(high, 24)
ema7        = ta.ema(high, 27)
ema8        = ta.ema(high, 30)
ema9        = ta.ema(high, 33)
ema10        = ta.ema(high, 36)
ema11        = ta.ema(high, 39)
ema12       = ta.ema(high, 42)
ema13       = ta.ema(high, 45)
ema14        = ta.ema(high, 48)
ema15        = ta.ema(high, 51)
// Colors
green       = #2BBC4D, red     = #C51D0B
emaEnergyColor(ma) => emaEnergy ? (close >= ma ? green : red) : na
// Plots
plot(ema1, "", emaEnergyColor(ema1), editable=false)
plot(ema2, "", emaEnergyColor(ema2), editable=false)
plot(ema3, "", emaEnergyColor(ema3), editable=false)
plot(ema4, "", emaEnergyColor(ema4), editable=false)
plot(ema5, "", emaEnergyColor(ema5), editable=false)
plot(ema6, "", emaEnergyColor(ema6), editable=false)
plot(ema7, "", emaEnergyColor(ema7), editable=false)
plot(ema8, "", emaEnergyColor(ema8), editable=false)
plot(ema9, "", emaEnergyColor(ema9), editable=false)
plot(ema10, "", emaEnergyColor(ema10), editable=false)
plot(ema11, "", emaEnergyColor(ema11), editable=false)
plot(ema12, "", emaEnergyColor(ema12), editable=false)
plot(ema13, "", emaEnergyColor(ema13), editable=false)
plot(ema14, "", emaEnergyColor(ema14), editable=false)
plot(ema15, "", emaEnergyColor(ema15), editable=false)
[supertrend, direction] = supertrend(close, sensitivity, 11, keltner_length)
bull = ta.crossover(close, supertrend)
bear = ta.crossunder(close, supertrend)
y1 = low - (ta.atr(30) * 2)
y2 = high + (ta.atr(30) * 2)
buy  = bull ? label.new(bar_index, y1, "BUY", xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, green, label.style_label_up, color.white, size.normal) : na
sell = bear ? label.new(bar_index, y2, "SELL", xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, red, label.style_label_down, color.white, size.normal) : na
[supertrends, directions] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)
bodyMiddle = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
// Trend Catcher Indicator (Example)
ema100 = ta.ema(close, 10)
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 20)
trendCatcher = ta.crossover(ema100, ema200) ? 1 : ta.crossunder(ema100, ema200) ? -1 : 0
trendColor = trendCatcher == 1 ? color.rgb(90, 23, 102) : na
barcolor(trendColor)
// Colored candles
barcolor(color = close > supertrends ? color.rgb(102, 255, 0) : color.rgb(255, 0, 0))
// Alerts
alertcondition(bull, title="Buy", message="Buy!")
alertcondition(bear, title="Sell", message="Sell!")
```

When I attach the strategy info below I get the error.

```
// Get user input
//entryPips = input.float(title='Entry Pips', defval=3.0, tooltip='How many pips above high to place entry order')
stopPips = input.float(title='Stop Pips', defval=5.0, tooltip='Fixed pip stop loss distance')
targetPips = input.float(title='Target Pips', defval=10.0, tooltip='Fixed pip profit target distance')

// Determine buy & sell point (default 3 pips/30 points above/below high/low)
buyPoint = buy //dailyHigh + entryPips * 10 * syminfo.mintick
sellPoint = sell //dailyLow - entryPips * 10 * syminfo.mintick

// Determine stop loss (default 5 pips/50 points above/below buy/sell point)
stopLossLong = strategy.position_avg_price - stopPips * 10 * syminfo.mintick
stopLossShort = strategy.position_avg_price + stopPips * 10 * syminfo.mintick

// Determine take profit (default 10 pips/100 points above/below buy/sell point)
takeProfitLong = strategy.position_avg_price + targetPips * 10 * syminfo.mintick
takeProfitShort = strategy.position_avg_price - targetPips * 10 * syminfo.mintick

//Strategy Entry Here
strategy.entry('bull', strategy.long, qty = long_qty)
strategy.exit('bull exit', stop = stopLossLong, profit = takeProfitLong)
strategy.entry('bear', strategy.short, qty = short_qty)
strategy.exit('bull exit', stop = stopLossShort, profit = takeProfitShort)
//Take Profit and Stop Loss Inputs

// Get highs and lows
//dailyHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
//dailyLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)
```

Comment: Without strolling through that lengthy code, the error means you have placed too many orders on the chart (closed ones as well). This can happen if the chart has too many data and, say, goes back to 1990. Limit you trading to a certain time window, like, do not start trading until 2022 and then your code will only place orders when passing the year 2022.

Comment: I tried using the date filter in there. No luck.

Comment: If you narrow the date filter to a single day, and you checked that you really start trades on that single day, do you get the same error? That means you are still doing 9000 trades on that single day. Or some of the filtering is not working and you are still starting trades anytime or at least out of the time window. 
In the Strategy Tester / List of Trades do you see any trade entry?